# Faking the presence of a USB device in order to test driver installation on Windows

Tags: windows, wix, usb, windows-installer, drivers

I've been asked to help with some problems that a company are having with an Windows installer  they have that includes some custom driver installation for some hardware they make.

I've got access to the source code to build the software and installer (which is an WIX/MSI one), but don't have access to the hardware, so can't actually test it properly.

Is it possible (either with a toolkit, or without) to trick windows into thinking that a specific device USB device has been attached to the computer in order to trigger Windows into trying to install the drivers? . I've got access to all the Vendoer Id, DeviceID, etc information.

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 1):

That should be possible. Take a look at **WDK USBSamp** and **NDIS Virtual miniport (or virtual serial driver)** samples. The first one is a USB driver sample and second one demonstrates how to build virtual driver. You should be able to combine the two to create a virtual USB driver.